# Not able to catch all li elements inside ul using scrapy response xpath

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, html-lists

I'm trying to scrape articles available on [this website](https://www.langhamhospitalitygroup.com/en/media/latest-news/) using scrapy. I'm trying using the following code.

```
class Langham_Crawler(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "Langham Hotels"

    def __init__(self, target_date, scraped_data_list, **kwargs):
        self.target_date = parser.parse(target_date).date()
        self.start_urls = ['https://www.langhamhospitalitygroup.com/en/media/latest-news/']
        self.scraped_data_list = scraped_data_list
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        next_page_flag = True

        articles= response.xpath('.//*[@id="js-media-article-container"]/li/div')
```

But it is returning an empty list. Why can't I catch li elements using xpaths in scrapy.

[image: Please see the html code of this]

Answer (score 0):

That is because the text on the website is not present at the source. After I checked the XHR request in Inspect > Network, I found this XML for your website:

https://www.langhamhospitalitygroup.com/api/en/releases/36897/1?format=json&format=json

You can easily scrape this XML using [BeautifulSoup Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/beautiful_soup/index.htm)